# How do I invoke a click on the google search button in webview android SDK?

Tags: javascript, android, invoke, getelementbyid

I'm making an android app that consist of a webview & a button. 
The webview will load google.com on startup & your supposed to be able to type anything you want into the google search box, then click on the "Search" button at the bottom of my app & it will invoke a click on google's "Google Search" button that's on the page inside the webview.

Here's the problem... I'm fairly new to android development & I don't know how to getelement classname invoke a click on a button that's inside of the webview by clicking a button on my layout.

Here is the code for the "Google Search" button...
http://pastebin.com/NCvnAvb1

Also, below is a diagram to what the main.xml layout looks like

http://i44.tinypic.com/21jp09g.png

Please post a reply if you know the code so I can type something into the search bar then click on my layout's search button & it will search google.

Thanks.

EDIT: I now have this code... 
but it's telling me "document cannot be resolved"

webview.evaljs(document.getElementsByClassName("google search button blah").click());

however now eclipse is telling me "document cannon be resolved".

Anyone know how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, your approach is a bad idea.  It would be possible to achieve what you're asking, but, (and I haven't thought about how to achieve it) your result would be fragile.  There are about 2843 things Google could change which would break your code.

There is an [official Google API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html)  you can use but you're limited to 100 free queries per day unless you sign up for Google billing, in which case Google might charge you for more searches.

Alternatively, you could provide your own search box, perhaps in a layout that looks like the Google home page, then construct the search URL and pass it back to Google.com

You might want to consider using Yahoo/Bing instead as they provide unlimited queries.  See [here](http://www.codexperiments.com/java/2011/01/create-your-own-web-search-application/) for a good overview.

Comment: I understand what your saying but I still want to figure out how to invoke a click onto the search button. If you know any other resource's please let me know.